# Multi module build in maven or separate builds

Tags: maven, multi-module

I have to make build architecture of my small project and I wonder how to proceed?

I have classes in one project for the so call `core-part` which can be used in other projects and `api` part in the first project which uses `core-part`.

*So how to act?*

1. To make multi-module Maven build and to produce 2 artifacts (which to upload to our company repo) and `api-part` have project dependency to `core-part`:

   ```
   pom.xml
   |
   /core-part
   |
   /api-part(depends on core-part)
   ```

   2. Create separate projects

*Project1*

```
/core-part
|
pom.xml
```

*Project2*

```
/api-part
|
pom.xml -> depends on project1's GAV artifact
```

*Project3 ,...n* depends on project1?

Answer (score 2):

"Strong advice" : a project belongs in a multi-module build if release of that build requires release of that module, **and vice versa**.  Multi-module projects should consist of things that must be released together.

An API should [practically] never depend on the release of its implementation, whereas the release of an API [nearly always] dictates the release of a new dependent implementation.

If you're not doing formal releases (why aren't you doing formal releases?) then this advice is still in force but less strong.

Answer (score 0):

1. is the way if you'd like to build `core-part` and `api-part` within one build by building the *aggregator/multi-module* project (which has to have `<packaging>pom`).

There is actually a third artifact created (and installed and deployed to the repositories) then: The one for the aggregator project.

2. is the way if you'd like to handle (build, install, deploy) `core-part` and `api-part` individually. (An option you still have with 1. anyway.)

See:

- [POM Reference, Aggregation (or Multi-Module)](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Aggregation)
- [Maven: The Complete Reference, 3.6.2. Multi-module vs. Inheritance](http://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/pom-relationships-sect-pom-best-practice.html#pom-relationships-sect-multi-vs-inherit).